# Find the next number and what I am!

Tags: number-sequence

This is the first puzzle I made and apparently it's too difficult.
So I tried to create hints, but it's hard.
If you have any ideas on how to write this riddle in a better way, or have more "mathematical" advice to give me, I would be really glad!

Find the next number and what I am!

> 111
>   121
>   133
>   114
>   641
>   1510
>   ???

Hint 1:

> As you see me right now, I've been destroyed, cut, then reorganized.

Hint 2:

> I currently am cut in equal pieces

Hint 3:

> My "creator" is not the devil but is French.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Some advice right off the bat: when posting a puzzle here, we prefer that people wait a day or two before adding hints, rather than providing them with the puzzle immediately. But you're asking for advice on how to write the puzzle in such a way that the hints aren't necessary, so it's obviously not a problem in this instance.

Comment: I'm not sure how hard it is to find the solution so I put hints to see if it really help or not but I keep your advice in mind for later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The next number will be

> 1051

And then

> 1615

You are

> the Pascal triangle, from french mathematician Blaise Pascal

It was feaseble without the hints, but the first hint confirm my thought.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that there is an error in the line '114?'

Comment: Given this is the correct answer, I would think the first hint is sufficient, or alternatively, putting the numbers at each “line break” from the original pattern in bold.

Comment: @ZanyG the line`114` is correct.

Comment: @AlainRemillard Oh nevermind. I forgot the one from the previous line.

Comment: @Earlien I'm afraid this hint may oversimplify the puzzle. But it's a real hint about the puzzle, not as my other hints. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @ZanyG Did you know the existence of Pascal's triangle?

Comment: @Olivier Yes, my mistake was misreading the line 133. I thought it had said 1331.

Comment: @AlainRemillard Did you know the Pascal's Triangle?

Comment: @Olivier As soon as I saw the `121` line I thought of it. I love to do math contest and it often appear in the problems' solutions.